# php open a modal dialog when sending a form

Tags: php, forms, modal-dialog

I got a problem with my modal dialog when i send my form. i would like to keep the modal dialog when i press the send button and display submitting succeessfully, but it doesn't do it.

This is my form code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php?page=contact">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Contact</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
                        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
                        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
                        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errHuman</p>";?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <?php echo $result; ?>    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

When this is my php code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $human = intval($_POST['human']);
    $from = 'your email'; 
    $to = 'example@domain.com'; 
    $subject = 'your subject';

    $body = "From: $name\nE-Mail: $email\nMessage:\n $message";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }
    //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
    if ($human !== 5) {
        $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
    }

    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from, $email)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Where is jQuery code?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to reopen your modal after you submit your form ( if you are not using Ajax ), try using this on your modal page:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     <?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])): ?>
        $('#contact').modal('show');
     <?php endif; ?>
 });
```

Comment: i tried it, but the browser respond Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: The `$` from `$(document)` or `$('#contact')` refers to jQuery.Are you using my code before you loaded jQuery?

Comment: yes, i did. first of all i put all my script in the footer, on the top there is the jquery's and after that all the scripts i need